# Freeze state position on animation css

Tags: css, animation

I would like on `hover` save the image position of `.pole-main .pole-gatherings .img:hover` element.

Freeze it's up with `animation` css effect

When `hover` is out I would like to animate it back

As provided in `.pole-main .pole-gatherings .img:hover`

https://jsfiddle.net/kb2grhL5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your animation from keyframe to transition:

```
  .pole-main .pole-gatherings .img{
    width: 283px;
    height: 102px;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: transform .7s;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  .pole-main .pole-gatherings .img:hover{
    transform: perspective(300px) rotateY(-5deg);
  }
```